# Counting number of pattern matches in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, multiple-matches

I am VERY new to perl, and to programming in general. 
I have been searching for the past couple of days on how to count the number of pattern matches; I have had a hard time understanding others solutions and applying them to the code I have already written.

Basically, I have a sequence and I need to find all the patterns that match [TC]C[CT]GGAAGC

I believe I have that part down. but I am stuck on counting the number of occurrences of each pattern match. Does anyone know how to edit the code I already have to do this? Any advice is welcomed. Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

# open fasta file for reading 
unless( open( FASTA, "<", '/scratch/Drosophila/dmel-all-chromosome-    r6.02.fasta' )) {
    die "Can't open dmel-all-chromosome-r6.02.fasta for reading:", $!;
}

#split the fasta record
local $/ = ">";

#scan through fasta file 
while (<FASTA>) {
    chomp;
    if ( $_ =~ /^(.*?)$(.*)$/ms) {
            my $header = $1;
            my $seq = $2;
            $seq =~ s/\R//g; # \R removes line breaks 
                    while ( $seq  =~ /([TC]C[CT]GGAAGC)/g) {
                            print $1, "\n";
            }
    }
}
```

Update, I have added in

```
my @matches = $seq =~ /([TC]C[CT]GGAAGC)/g;
                            print scalar @matches;
```

In the code below. However, it seems to be outputting 0 in front of each pattern match, instead of outputting the total sum of all pattern matches.

```
while (<FASTA>) {
    chomp;
    if ( $_ =~ /^(.*?)$(.*)$/ms) {
            my $header = $1;
            my $seq = $2;
            $seq =~ s/\R//g; # \R removes line breaks 
                    while ( $seq  =~ /([TC]C[CT]GGAAGC)/g) {
                            print $1, "\n";
                            my @matches = $seq =~ /([TC]C[CT]GGAAGC)/g;
                            print scalar @matches;
    }
    }
}
```

Edit: I need the output to list ever pattern match found. I also need it to find the total number of matches found. For example:

CCTGGAAGC

TCTGGAAGC

TCCGGAAGC

3 matches found

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own post.

Comment: Do not vandalize your questions

Answer (score 4):

> counting the number of occurrences of each pattern match

```
my @matches = $string =~ /pattern/g
```

`@matches` array will contain all the matched parts. You can then do below to get the count.

```
print scalar @matches
```

Or you could directly write

```
my $matches = () = $string =~ /pattern/
```

I would suggest you to use the former as you might need to check "what was matched" in future (perhaps for debugging?).

Example 1:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = 'John Doe John Done';
my $matches = () = $string =~ /John/g;
print $matches; #prints 2
```

Example 2:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = 'John Doe John Done';
my @matches = $string =~ /John/g;
print "@matches"; #prints John John
print scalar @matches; #prints 2
```

Edit:

```
while ( my @matches = $seq  =~ /([TC]C[CT]GGAAGC)/g) {
    print $1, "\n";
    print "Count of matches:". scalar @matches;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. You can now use it in scalar context to get the count, like `print scalar @matches`. Try it and find out.

Comment: I have added examples in the answer to clear your doubt. Hope that helps.

Comment: Share the update code. You can edit your question to include that.

Comment: Just checked the updated question. You are doing it wrong. You should write the `@matches` in while loop line. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need the global `/g` flag to get all matches within your first couple of examples.

Comment: @stevieb: Yes. I have already used the `/g` flag in both examples.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean examples. I meant up at the top of the post: `my @matches = $string =~ /pattern/` and `my $matches = () = $string =~ /pattern/`

Comment: Thanks for your patience, Chankey. I tried writing the @ matches in the while loop line. However, the output now outputs a 1 in front of every pattern match. For example: 
Count of matches:1CCCGGAAGC
Count of matches:1CCCGGAAGC
Count of matches:1CCCGGAAGC
Count of matches:1CCCGGAAGC

Comment: It's printing 1 because it's finding only one occurrence of `([TC]C[CT]GGAAGC)` in each line. Please clearly mention what is the output that you are expecting?

Comment: I need the output to list every pattern match found. I also need it to find the total number of matches found. For example:
TCTGGAGC
CCTGGAGC
TCCGGAGC
3 matches found.

Comment: @Ashley do you want to print each match as it's found, then when the script is done print the count of all matches? If so you need a variable to store the number of matches and add to it every time the while loop matches. Then print that variable at the end outside of all loops. Georg's answer has an example. Your code prints the count each time through the while loop. Sometimes that's zero so you get "TCCG...\n0TCT..." because it prints: match, count (without newline), next match. Invite me to chat if this is unclear and you want more details.

Comment: @benrifkah I don't want to print the count number of each match every time a match is found. I just want to print the final, total number of matches at the bottom of the output. I am having a hard time removing the count number that is listed in front of each match from Georg's answer. And to be honest, I cannot figure out how to start/invite you to chat!

Comment: @You want to print the count only once at the end. That's what my comment said and that is what Georg's answer does.

Comment: @benrifkah I see now. Everything is working great. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As you have written the code, you have to count the  matches yourself:

```
local $/ = ">";
my $count = 0;

#scan through fasta file 
while (<FASTA>) {
    chomp;
    if ( $_ =~ /^(.*?)$(.*)$/ms) {
            my $header = $1;
            my $seq = $2;
            $seq =~ s/\R//g; # \R removes line breaks 
                    while ( $seq  =~ /([TC]C[CT]GGAAGC)/g) {
                            print $1, "\n";
                            $count = $count +1;
            }
    }
}
print "Fount $count matches\n";
```

should do the job.

HTH Georg

Answer (score 1):

```
my @count = ($seq  =~ /([TC]C[CT]GGAAGC)/g);
print scalar @count ;
```

Comment: sorry for delay results comes out with good count.
but problem with our inner while loop please remove that and try.

#  while ( $seq  =~ /([TC]C[CT]GGAAGC)/g) {
  #                          print $1, "\n";
                            my @matches = $seq =~ /([TC]C[CT]GGAAGC)/g;
                            print scalar @matches;
   # }